How do I install cordova with npm?
I'm trying to install cordova and I get this message every time.
C:\Users\Adam>npm i cordova
npm WARN deprecated npmlog@7.0.1: This package is no longer supported.
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "npm:": npm:string-width@^4.2.0
I've tried npm i string-width@4.2.0 but that does this:
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Adam\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Adam\package.json'
npm WARN Adam No description
npm WARN Adam No repository field.
npm WARN Adam No README data
npm WARN Adam No license field.

string-width@4.2.0
updated 1 package in 2.456s

can anyone help me install cordova?
I had an older version of cordova installed at first, I was trying to update it but I ultimately removed it and updated npm and node.  I'm ready to try installing cordova again but it errors. I'm on Windows 10.

npm install cordova -g

npm WARN deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm WARN deprecated npmlog@7.0.1: This package is no longer supported.
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "npm:": npm:string-width@^4.2.0

I'm just not getting how to resolve this.  I feel like I'm going to have to purchase a new computer to get Cordova again.  If anybody can help, it would be great!

what's your node version?

Eric:  I'm running node version 8.9.4

You need node >=16.13.0

I got it working.  Thanks for your help!  I'm now having a problem with running cordova run android - Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Command failed with exit code 1: gradle -p c:\Users\Adam\myApp2\platforms\android\tools wrapper --gradle-version 8.7

Well I installed Android Studio and cordova run android now errors a little cleaner.  I still don't know how to resolve the issue though.  Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio

Ok, I've got cordova, gradle, jdk and android sdk installed good.  But when I run cordova run android, it builds the .apk but errors with this: Built the following apk(s):
C:\Users\Adam\myApp2\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apkCommand failed with exit code 1: apkanalyzer manifest target-sdk C:\Users\Adam\myApp2\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

So... Its building the .apk but not loading it on a connected device or emulator yet.

Personally had the same problem. I was using latest version Node.js 20.13.1.
However, I got it to work after installing Node.js v18.17.1. After installation was following Cordova guide and all worked fine!
So I think just get Node.js v18.17.1. And follow the Cordova guide.
And yes, few error are still displayed, but at least it works.
I reckon, the problem is due to the version of certain packages, that do not work with latest Node.js.
Edit: Make sure you have set up all PATHs in Environment Variables for JDK and Graddle as well. Also in Android Studio itself the folder with SDK may not be provided. Maybe due to this you have those errors.
P.S.: (I am not able to write comments yet)

I'm now running node 20.14.0 and cordova seems to be running fine.  Please take a look at my new comment above.
